# How to modify the default value of a Material UI prop-function in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm working with React JS and I've imported from Material UI a component called  (https://material-ui.com/api/table-pagination/) and I would like to modify the Default of labelDisplayedRows that now is like this:

```
({ from, to, count }) => ${from}-${to} of ${count}
```

I would like to edit the "of" of the output, but it's a function, and so i don't know how to do it.
If it was a simple node like labelRowsPerPage I would modify it by writing

```
<TablePagination
                    labelRowsPerPage="text text text"
/>
```

How could I do it? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Give it a function which returns the string you need? Where exactly is your issue?

Comment: the solution is kind like this: <TablePagination labelDisplayedRows={({ from, to, count }) => `Displaying pages ${from}-${to} of total ${count} pages`}/>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<TablePagination labelDisplayedRows={({ from, to, count }) => `Displaying pages ${from}-${to} of total ${count} pages`}/>
```